# Restorative Touch vs Slow

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature, cleric, healing

The [Restoration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo-domains/healing-domain/restoration/) subdomain of the cleric's Healing domain grants a supernatural ability called Restorative Touch:

> You can touch a creature, letting the healing power of your deity flow through you to relieve the creature of a minor condition. Your touch can remove the dazed, fatigued, shaken, sickened, or staggered condition. You choose which condition is removed. You can use this ability a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Wisdom modifier.

How does this interact with spells, most notably [Slow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/), which cause Staggered *and other effects*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It will remove the condition, but not the whole spell effect

[Conditions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/conditions) are a separate mechanic from the spells. Some spells may cause conditions, but they are not tied together. Conditions are usually easier to remove than entire spells, as there are many class abilities and items (alchemical or magical) that can remove certain conditions.

Spells with a duration will not apply their effects again unless the spell's effect says so, such as the entangled condition from [Entangled](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/entangle/), or the grappled condition from [Web](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/web/). It is possible to walk into the area of the *Entangle* spell, get the entangled condition, remove it and walk away to safety. But if you remain inside the area, the spell's text will describe when the condition is re-applied (if that's the case).

For most spells, however, the effect is only applied once, like for *Instantaneous* or *Permanent* spells. As such, the effect of removing the condition is quite clear: It is gone and the spell won't apply it again. For *Instantaneous* spells, the magic happens and then dissipates, generating a non-magical effect that is permanent and must be removed by any means. *Permanent* spells are similar, but the spell lingers on the target, meaning that not only it creates an everlasting condition, but may also be [dispelled](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/).

Since [Slow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slow/) affects several creatures, using *Restorative Touch* on a single creature will remove the [staggered](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Staggered) condition for that creature only, while they are still affected by the *Slow* spell and still affected by the penalties and movement reduction:

> a -1 penalty on attack rolls, AC, and Reflex saves. A slowed creature moves at half its normal speed

[Dispel Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/) could remove the entire spell from all targets if you target the *spell* instead of targeting a creature. And [Remove Paralysis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-paralysis/) could remove the spell from a single creature, as it says:

> You can free one or more creatures from the effects of temporary paralysis or related magic, **including spells** and effects that cause a creature to gain the **staggered condition**.

Another example of this interaction is the [Glitterdust](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glitterdust/) spell (causes [blinded](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Blinded)) and [Remove Blindness/Deafness](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-blindness-deafness/). You could remove the condition but not the spell's effects.

Comment: There is one important distinction between *slow* and all other spells that you've mentioned. With *slow*, affected creatures "**are** staggered", with everything else they **become** blinded/grappled/entangled/etc and are *allowed saving throw each turn* to overcome the condition.

Comment: If you **gain** a condition you **are** under that condition. Im not sure whats the point of discussing semantics. If you gain the blinded condition, you are blinded.

Comment: The point is the difference in **how** the condition is gained. With entangle/web/glitterdust, it's an optional condition from the spell. With slow, it comes with the bundle. Hence the difference in semantics.

Comment: To me, in all three spells, that is part of the spell's effect.

Comment: It's still optional. You can be covered in glitterdust, but not blinded. You can stay in the web, but not be stuck. You can stay in area of entangle, but not be entangled. These options are all part of spell description. With slow, there is no such option. You are staggered as long as you are affected.

Comment: You realize that this ruling turns nearly all of the paladin's mercies useless, right? You cant remove shaken because it was applied by a spell or ability, you cant remove staggered because it was applied by Slow, you cant remove frightened because it was caused by *Cause Fear* or a *Dragon's Roar*, etc

Comment: It will render paladin's mercies useless in a relatively small amount of cases - only against ongoing targeted spells with timed duration, which is relatively few. Effects caused by instantaneous spells, spells that only apply the removable condition on the onset, or other abilities will still be removable as normal.

Comment: "are relatively few", lets agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanics do exactly what they say - they don't cancel the entire spell, or do anything about other effects. Restorative Touch simply removes the Staggered condition. In the case of being under a Slow spell, the recipient would still suffer the modifiers, and the half speed.

Answer (score 1):

### It depends on the spell.

Restorative Touch will remove one minor condition of your choice. If this condition was gained as an aftereffect of the spell with an instantaneous duration (like *Snowball* or *Frigid Touch*), alchemist's *Frost Bomb*, Staggering Critical feat or the like, the condition is removed.

However, *Slow* is an ongoing spell (Duration: 1 round/level). Its magical energies linger for several rounds, slowing the creatures for the duration, therefore the staggered condition will just be immediately reapplied.

Let's start with spell durations as outlined in Magic section of CRB:

> **Timed Durations**
>   Many durations are measured in rounds, minutes, hours, or other increments. ***When the time is up, the magic goes away and the spell ends.*** If a spell’s duration is variable, the duration is rolled secretly so the caster doesn’t know how long the spell will last.
>
> **Instantaneous**
>   The spell energy comes and goes the instant the spell is cast, though the consequences might be long-lasting.

Note the emphasis. It strongly implies that the effect is tied to the spell energy being in place; as soon as it's exhausted, the effect goes away.

Let's consider a following scenario. Our 4th level party standing off against evil wizard Wendy. She wins initiative and casts *[Hypnotism](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hypnotism/)* on the party's barbarian Bob, who fails his will save and is now fascinated for, say, 5 rounds (average of 2d4). Party sorcerer Stella counters that by casting *[Suppress charms and compulsions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/suppress-charms-and-compulsions/)*, breaking Bob's fascination, who is now set on murdering Wendy for the insult and charges the poor girl. However, he does not notice the evil ranger Ralph, who shoots an arrow at Stella the next round, breaking her concentration. With *Suppress charms and compulsions* now gone, Bob again falls under the ongoing energies of *Hypnotism* and is fascinated again.

Stella is now furious, so she pulls out a scroll of *Dispel Magic* and succeeds on UMD check to cast it, and also succeeds a caster level check to dispell *Hypnotism*. With spell energies now gone, Bob is no longer fascinated and can rip Wendy a new one.

Now, let's suppose that Wendy still not done and casts *[Frigid Touch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/frigid-touch/)* and crits on a touch attack, staggering Bob for a full minute. Now, note that unlike *Hypnotism*, duration of *Frigid Touch* is instantaneous, so spell's energies are gone and Stella can't dispel the effect. Thankfully, cleric Charlie finally catches up to the rest of the party and uses his *Restorative Touch* on Bob, ending his stunned condition.

Note that how fascination comes and goes with spell energies being suppressed, restored and finally dismissed. Same effect would happen if, say, instead of Stella casting *Suppress Charms and Compulsions*, rogue Rob would bring an artifact stone with permanent *Antimagic Field* next to Bob, and then him being bull rushed out of range by Ralph's ram animal companion.

In short, to remove an effect caused by ongoing magic, you deal with magic itself, not the effect. Removing an aftereffect of magic use, you deal with the effect itself.

Comment: The implications of this seem overwhelming. Can this answer offer evidence that spells reassert themselves automatically when an effect partially removes one or more of their elements? (My fear would be that this reading makes many condition-removal effects useless, making it so the ability restorative touch or even the spell [*greater restoration*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/restoration/) can't remove the fatigued condition caused by the spell [*touch of fatigue*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/touch-of-fatigue/), for example.) (Not stalking! I swear!)

Comment: I feel like this is the logical conclusion based on the specific situation, but without more backing this would be a Rule 0 override, not the RAW method of gameplay (unless there is something that says differently... which is why I asked)

Comment: It's to do with effects and durations. I will try to write an expanded answer tonight, barring the real life interference (which is somewhat likely at this stage). Keep tuned!

Comment: @HeyICanChan See the expanded answer. Basically, yes, greater restoration will not remove effect caused by touch of fatigue, but dispel magic will. (and I didn't accuse you of stalking! Pathfinder tag is not very active, it's just a small crammed space down here)

Comment: I understand your example, but in the case of the question, I think it'd be more useful if the example were to focus on *removing* — rather than *suppressing* — conditions. That is, this answer makes it sound like casting on one target *remove paralysis* would only suppress (for 1 round or less) the *slow* spell but casting *remove paralysis* on multiple targets would give each target the chance to be utterly free of the *slow* spell. That *could* totally be *technically* accurate, but it seems to go against what I imagine most think the effect of a spell called *remove paralysis* should have.

Comment: (And some newer users are occasionally surprised when the same user comments on more than one of their answers, the Internet being a paranoid place. Your assessment of the *Pathfinder* subcommunity here just being small—and me not stalking—is absolutely accurate. Thank you for having perspective!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I've looked at suppressing magic specifically to showcase how conditions come and go with the flow of magic.

Comment: wording of *remove paralysis* suggests that it will completely negate *slow* when cast on a single character because of "or related magic...gain the staggered condition" clause.

Comment: My fault for a bad example, but the sentiment remains.

Comment: @ShadowKras Wouldn't it? "When a creature takes damage from this spell, they become dazed ..." Of course this is wildly powerful, but so is AoE Daze (the more common use of the spell) There's a reason I don't allow this Feat in my games >.>

Comment: @ShadowKras Yes, you are reading it correct. Dazed condition applies "when a creature takes damage from the spell", not "first time when creature takes damage from the spell". Which is OK with me, given that it requires a spell slot 3 levels higher.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 4+ rounds of Daze on a touch attack (no save, no SR) is more powerful than most 5th level spells...